# from, pipe, and map Observables logic?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to better understand concepts or RxJS, and here is a simple example that I wasn't sure if I understood everything correctly:

```
from([1,2,3,]).pipe(
map((data)=>{
    console.log(data,'map');
    return data
  })
)
.subscribe(data=>console.log(data, 'from subscribe'))
/*
1 map
1 from subscribe
2 map
2 from subscribe
3 map
3 from subscribe
*/
```

Here is what I think happens:

1. When we call `subscribe`, first `map` subscribes to `from` Observable.
2. Each value emitted by `from` is console logged and emitted back from `map` as an individual Observable. So, in this case we would have 3 Observables.
3. `.subscribe` subscribes to each Observable from `map` (Observable that resolves with 1, another Observable that resolves with 2, .... ) and we see another log.

After looking at documentation, I think I got something wrong with my current understanding of how things are working.

I'd appreciate if someone could confirm or correct the logic I described in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`from`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) -> converts the array into a stream of observables that are emitted one by one.
- [`map`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) -> accesses the value of the observable and you have the option to transform the data if needed, the input parameter is not a observable, the output value is also not an observable.
- [`subscribe`](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments) -> for each emitted value the subscribe next block is called (the function which is passed.

Subscribe has three sections, subscribe has three arguments.

- `next` ->  called when an observable emits an value, will continue to be called on each emit until the observable completes
- `error` ->  called when an there is an error on the observable stream, could be non intentional (coding error) or manual error `throw new Error('failed')`
- `complete` -> will get called once the observable stream completes.

In your example, next block is called three times (in your case the console.log) after that finally the complete block is called. To better understand it, here is a working example highlighting the same!

```
import './style.css';

import { rx, of, map, from } from 'rxjs';

from([1, 2, 3])
  .pipe(
    map((data) => {
      console.log(data, 'map');
      return data;
    })
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (data: any) => {
      console.log(data, 'from subscribe next');
    },
    error: (data: any) => {
      console.log(data, 'from subscribe error');
    },
    complete: () => {
      console.log('from subscribe complete');
    },
  });
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zkzyhf?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts,node_modules%2Frxjs%2Fdist%2Ftypes%2Finternal%2FObservable.d.ts,lib.es5.d.ts)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I got from documentation `map Applies a given project function to each value emitted by the source Observable, and emits the resulting values as an Observable.` .

Comment: @Noob Yes, but the gist is it transforms the data and emits it again, without subscribing to access the data!

Answer (score 0):

`pipe` acts as a data pipeline, similar to the `|` in Linux.

It takes an array of Operators that either transform the value like `map` or read a value without changing the data like `tap` or introduce a delay from a source observable.

`RxJs` has a rich set of operators that will help with creating complex pipelines that would be non trivial to implement from scratch. ex `Retry` or `shareReplay`

`subscribe` acts as a listener to the change in the data source i.e `from(1,2,3)`

In this case for each value in `from` pass data to `pipe` to perform some user defined transformations and listen to the changes using `subscribe`.